# Is there a processing library that allows for form elements?

Tags: processing

I am making an interactive graphics program in processing and would like a drop down menu.

Is there a processing library out there for form elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At  processing.org/reference/libraries/#interface they are some GUI libraries you could use.
I dont't tried, but I think that you can find something that will help you.
And good luck! ;)

Answer (score 0):

ControlP5 library (http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/) is probably one of the most often used libraries for GUI stuff.